# Rspec namespaced route specs failing even though route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm using **rspec-rails (2.8.1)** and **rails 3.1.3**.

I'm trying to test routes for my Admin::ZonesController.  I have verified the route exists in both the browser and by running `rake routes`.  I am not using ActiveRecord (if that matters).  When I run the routing spec, it tells me:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/admin/zones/new"
```

Here is the test (spec/routing/admin/zones_routing_spec.rb):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "routing to zones" do

  it "routes /admin/zones/new to admin/zones#new" do
    { :get => "/admin/zones/new" }.should route_to(
      :controller => "admin/zones",
      :action => "new"
    )
  end
end
```

Here is the controller action whose route I am trying to test (admin/zones#new):

```
class Admin::ZonesController < Admin::BaseController

  before_filter :instantiate_variables

  def new
    @zone = Zone.new
    @campaign = Campaign.new
    @rules = [Rule.new]
  end
end
```

Running `rake routes` gives me this:

```
                  POST   /hooks/:resource(.:format)           {:controller=>"hooks", :action=>"create"}
                  POST   /services/:service/:method(.:format) {:controller=>"services", :action=>"create"}
      admin_zones GET    /admin/zones(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
                  POST   /admin/zones(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
   new_admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
  edit_admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/:id/edit(.:format)      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
       admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
                  PUT    /admin/zones/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
                  DELETE /admin/zones/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/zones"}
    admin_widgets GET    /admin/widgets(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
                  POST   /admin/widgets(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
 new_admin_widget GET    /admin/widgets/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
edit_admin_widget GET    /admin/widgets/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
     admin_widget GET    /admin/widgets/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
                  PUT    /admin/widgets/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
                  DELETE /admin/widgets/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/widgets"}
            zones GET    /zones(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"zones"}
                  POST   /zones(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"zones"}
         new_zone GET    /zones/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"zones"}
        edit_zone GET    /zones/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"zones"}
             zone GET    /zones/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"zones"}
                  PUT    /zones/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"zones"}
                  DELETE /zones/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"zones"}
             root        /                                    {:controller=>"admin/zones", :action=>"new"}
```

My **routes.rb** looks like this:

```
D2CModularPlatform::Application.routes.draw do

  post "/hooks/:resource" => "hooks#create"

  post "/services/:service/:method" => "services#create"

  namespace :admin do
    resources :zones
    resources :widgets
  end

  resources :zones

  root :to => "admin/zones#new"
end
```

My **controllers dir** looks like this:

- controllers

  - admin

    - base_controller
    - widgets_controller
    - zones_controller
  - application_controller
  - hooks_controller
  - services_controller
  - zones_controller

My **spec/routing** dir looks like this:

- spec/routing

  - admin

    - zones_routing_spec
  - hooks_routing_spec
  - services_routing_spec
  - zones_routing_spec

Comment: could it be related to this? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8679

Comment: certainly seems like it — thanks for the lead!

Comment: want to post your own answer to this?